# executing `AsyncTask` in android

Tags: android

How do I call my `AsyncTask` in `onCreate`? It never gets called. However, it gets called on `onPause` , so to simulate `onPause`, I just launched another activity and finished it, but with this approach, my app won't exit properly.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ExternalIP().execute((Void) null);
        open();
    }

    private void open() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sec.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private class ExternalIP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            String ip = "Empty";

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://wtfismyip.com/text");
                //http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON
                //http://wtfismyip.com/text
                HttpResponse response;

                response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    long len = entity.getContentLength();
                    if (len != -1 && len < 1024) {
                        String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        ip = str.replace("\n", "");

                        final TextView tvHelp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ip);
                        tvHelp1.setText("Public IP: " + ip);
                    } else {
                        ip = "Response too long or error.";
                    }
                } else {
                    ip = "Null:" + response.getStatusLine().toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                ip = "Error";
            }

            return ip;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // External IP
            Log.d("ExternalIP", result);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
new ExternalIP().execute();
```

already.

Comment: move open(); from oncreateView to onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

Try not doing `setText` in `doInBackground`, UI stuff should be done in UI thread. My bet is an exception is being thrown and gets hid cause you are doing pokemon exception handling.

Shift `setText` to `onPostExecute`, remove your open activity hack and try again :)

Comment: when i try to setText in onPost execute, it forgets my string ("ip")

Comment: if by forgets, you mean onPostExecute is receiving a null string, set up break points and logs to analyze the problem. Also please either log the caught exceptions or do a printStackTrace

Comment: i defined the string "ip" and i get a null string in my textfield sorry for not being clear

Comment: in `onPostExecute`, the String result is your ip

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `open();` method from where starting new Activity, just after starting AsyncTask use `onPostExecute` method which execute when `doInBackground` method execution complete:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // External IP
            Log.d("ExternalIP", result);
             open();
        }
```

Comment: any snippet of the onPostExecute method?

Comment: @pleaseMOM: issue is occurring because new Activity is started just after starting `AsyncTask ` which getting terminated because current Activity onStop method is called

Comment: @pleaseMOM: use means do tasks in onPostExecute  method like call `open ` in it

Comment: @pleaseMOM if you dont want to open new activity, just simpy remove open(); from your onCreate

Comment: @pleaseMOM: `i'm opening it just to simulate onPause ` then move current application in background by pressing Home Button of device not need to start any Activity to simulate onPause method

Comment: @pleaseMOM: in your code you have `onPostExecute ` method in `ExternalIP ` class right? so just add `open();` after ` Log.d("ExternalIP", result);` line

Comment: @pleaseMOM: Change `new ExternalIP().execute((Void) null);
        open();` to `new ExternalIP().execute((Void) null);` on onCreate method

Comment: i did that already, AKA removed the open(); method from onCreate

Answer (score 0):

> it never gets called

Because, You are starting new Activity before your AsyncTask completes.

Start your second Activity from `onPostExecute` of your AsyncTask class instead of from `onCreate`

Do Like this :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      Log.d("ExternalIP", result);
      open();
}
```

And remove `open();` from onCreate

Comment: @pleaseMOM You should look up some samples of `AsyncTask` use. Also understand that the `AsyncTask` is running in a separate, parallel thread, so it will continue to run as your activity gets destroyed and the new one is started.